# python selenium send_keys emoticons characters

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need send emoticons with selenium, for example:

���������✊���������

and selenium returns an error, I tested with `.send_keys(unicode(bio_text, 'ascii'))  # iso-8859-1`, the same result.

How can I send these characters with python selenium?

python code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("biography").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("biography").send_keys(unicode('���������✊���������', 'ascii'))  # iso-8859-1
```

emoticons example :

```
���������✊���������
```

Comment: You shoult try with `encode('utf-8')`. Without a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we cannot help a lot here ...

Comment: yess im try and gived the same error

Comment: And what is the error ?

Comment: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Also, your characters seems badly encoded ... Could you give a try with `''.encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: Are you use python 2?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')

text = u"''"
text = text.replace("'", "\\'")  # escape single quotes
text = text.encode('utf-8')  # needed to make format function work

driver.execute_script(
    "document.getElementById('lst-ib').value = '{data}'".format(
        data=text
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it with xpath

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
inp_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/xxxxxxxxx'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
text = ''
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '{}'".format(text),input_box)
input_box.send_keys('.')
input_box.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE +Keys.ENTER)
```