# Selenium throwing error when using emojis in send_keys function

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to use send_keys to populate a form on my website.
However, whenever I try to pass an emoji like so:

`''.decode('utf-8')`

I will encounter the following error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters`

This should be replicable on every python 2.7 installation.

Defining encoding like so: `#encoding=utf-8` does not change anything and the error persists.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I use send_keys in combination with emojis?

edit:

Changing the string to `u''.encode('utf-8')` and adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` the error is now: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data`

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use a proper Unicode string? I.e., `u''.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @PM2Ring , yes. The error code is now: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: unexpected end of data`

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Selenium, so I can't offer any more help. But FWIW, the UTF-8 encoded version of that string is `'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80\xf0\x9f\x98\x81\xf0\x9f\x98\x82\xf0\x9f\x98\x87\xf0\x9f\x98\xba'` or in Unicode-escapes, `u'\U0001f600\U0001f601\U0001f602\U0001f607\U0001f63a'`. Maybe Selenium just doesn't like those high range code points that emojis use.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for your help, I tried `u'\U0001f600\U0001f601\U0001f602\U0001f607\U0001f63a'` but unfortunately was confronted with the `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: missing command parameters` error again. Surely there must be a workaround even if selenium doesn't 'like' the high range code points,,

Comment: I think it's the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680238/python-selenium-send-keys-emoticons-characters/44779369#44779369.